# How to search for a collection with exact same relationship values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

I have these 3 tables **Apparel, Outfit, ApparelOutfit** (sample of table structure below). I want to check if an outfit exists using an array of apparel_ids in the ApparelOutfit pivot table. The array of apparel_ids should be exactly the same as the related apparel_ids of the outfit, no more no less. How should I do that?

```
-- Apparel --
id | name


-- Outfit --
id | is_favorite


-- ApparelOutfit -- (pivot table)
apparel_id | outfit_id
```

Comment: Please show the code of your attempt to achieve the desired output

Comment: I actually haven't tried any yet. But it goes something like this: Get the outfit_id where apparel_ids match [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Have you defined the models and relationships - Apparel and Outfit model classes with both ways relationships?

Comment: in Outfit model i have this. 

public function apparels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Apparel::class)
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->as('apparel_outfit')
            ->orderByPivot('apparel_id');
    }

Comment: I found this solution from others and it somehow works but I haven't fully tested it. can you confirm if this is a good solution?

`$outfits = Outfit::with(['apparels'])
            ->whereHas('apparels', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->whereIn('apparel_id', $request->apparel_ids);
            })
            ->whereDoesntHave('apparels', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->whereNotIn('apparel_id', $request->apparel_ids);
            })
            ->get(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your input via comment

> int OUtfit model i have this. public function apparels() { return $this->belongsToMany(Apparel::class) ->withTimestamps() ->as('apparel_outfit') ->orderByPivot('apparel_id'); }

You can try

Eg:

> say
> outfit1 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3]
> outfit2 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3,4]
> outfit3 has apparel_ids of[2,3,4]

```php
//Say you have the following apparel ids as request data
$apparelIds = [1,2,3];

$outfits = Outfit::query()
    ->whereHas(
        'apparels', 
        fn($query) => $query->whereIn('id', $apparelIds), 
        '=', 
        count($apparelIds)
    )
    /** If you want to get the records */
    ->get();
    /** If you just want how many outfits exist for the given $apparelIds
     * ->count();
     */
```

The above query will fetch **outfit1** and **outfit2**

For a strictly exact match

Eg:

> say
> outfit1 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3]
> outfit2 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3,4]
> outfit3 has apparel_ids of[2,3,4]

```php
//Say you have the following apparel ids as request data
$apparelIds = [1,2,3];

$outfits = Outfit::query()
    ->whereHas(
        'apparels', 
        fn($query) => $query->whereIn('id', $apparelIds)
    )
    ->whereDoesntHave(
        'apparels', 
        fn($query) => $query->whereNotIn('id', $apparelIds)
    )
    /** If you want to get the records */
    ->get();
    /** If you just want how many outfits exist for the given $apparelIds
     * ->count();
     */
```

The above query will fetch only **outfit1**

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: but this will also retrieve all outfits with apparel_ids more than [1,2,3] right? let's say outfit1 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3] and outfit2 has apparel_ids of [1,2,3,4]. both outfits will be return right? but I want only outfit1 to be returned

Comment: @EDGE Have updated answer. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: oh, i just checked it again, it retrieves outfit with more than the array passed

Comment: @EDGE Shouldn't be the case. I tested with sample data and it works flawlessly. It should only fetch records from `outfits` table which are having associated **apparels** exactly as per `$apparelIds` no more - no less

Comment: i'm using this code `public function scopeFilterExactApparels($query, $value) {
        return $query->whereHas('apparels', function ($query) use ($value) {
                $query->whereIn('apparel_id', $value);
            }, '=', count($value));
    }`

Comment: @EDGE What's the `$value` you pass in the scope? What data type it is? Is it an array of `apparel_id` something  like [1,2,3,4,5]. If not sure check for the value using `dd($value)` in the scope

Comment: it's an array of apparel ids [1,2,3,4]

Comment: i also tried it directly in the controller, still not working

Comment: still not working. idk why. it still returns outfits even with more than the parameters

Comment: still not working. and something's weird. coz i changed the count($apparel_ids) to random numbers and it returns different results. if i change it to 1, it returns outfit with 9 apparels. if i change it to 2, it returns with 2 and 4 apparels. and if i change it to 4, it returns nothing

Comment: @EDGE You were right. I had tested with very limited data earlier and missed out on exact match part testing with more data. Have updated answer to include **exact** match.